# Docker - Node.js + MongoDB - "Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, port, virtual-machine, docker

I am trying to create a container for my **Node** app. This app uses **MongoDB** to ensure some data persistence.
So I created this *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM    ubuntu:latest

# --- Installing MongoDB
# Add 10gen official apt source to the sources list
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
RUN echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list
# Hack for initctl not being available in Ubuntu
RUN dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
RUN ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
# Install MongoDB
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install mongodb-10gen
# Create the MongoDB data directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/db
CMD ["usr/bin/mongod", "--smallfiles"]

# --- Installing Node.js

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-software-properties python python-setuptools ruby rubygems
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js

# Fixing broken dependencies ("nodejs : Depends: rlwrap but it is not installable"):
RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs 

# Removed unnecessary packages
RUN apt-get purge -y python-software-properties python python-setuptools ruby rubygems
RUN apt-get autoremove -y

# Clear package repository cache
RUN apt-get clean all

# --- Bundle app source
ADD . /src
# Install app dependencies
RUN cd /src; npm install

EXPOSE  8080
CMD ["node", "/src/start.js"]
```

Then I build and launch the whole thing through:

```
$ sudo docker build -t aldream/myApp
$ sudo docker run aldream/myApp
```

But the machine displays the following error:

```
[error] Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually `docker run aldream/myApp`? In that case, with the Dockerfile that you provided, it should run MongODB, but not your app. Is there another `CMD` command, or another Dockerfile, or are you running `docker run aldream/myApp <somethingelse>`? In the latter case, it will override the `CMD` directive and MongoDB will not be started.

If you want to run multiple processes in a single container, you need a process manager (like e.g. Supervisor, god, monit) or start the processes in the background from a script; e.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh
mongod &
node myapp.js &
wait
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My bad for ignoring the fact that the containers were single-process. I opted for Supervisor, though I'm also currently trying to build separate containers for mongoDB and my app, to keep it more modular...

Answer (score 1):

Redefine your Dockerfile as follows;

```
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# ENTRYPOINT should not be used as it wont allow commands from run to be executed

# Define mountable directories.
VOLUME ["/data/db"]

# Expose ports.
#   - 27017: process
#   - 28017: http
#   - 9191: web app
EXPOSE 27017 28017 9191

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

supervisord.conf will contain the following;

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:mongod]
command=/usr/bin/mongod --smallfiles
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
autorestart=true

[program:nodejs]
command=nodejs /opt/app/server/server.js
```