# How to deploy mean stack application in docker?

Tags: docker, mean-stack

How to deploy a mean stack application in docker?
I have an error in mongodb connection.so mean stack web application is not responding.

Here are my steps:

1. Pulled the [image from DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/crissi/airlineinsurance/):

   ```
   sudo docker pull crissi/airlineinsurance
   ```
2. Verified Images

   ```
   sudo docker images
   ```
3. Run the mongodb Container

   ```
   sudo docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name airlineInsurance -d mongo
   ```
4. Verified it is running:

   ```
   sudo docker ps -l
   ```
5. Run the Application Container

   ```
   sudo docker run -d -P crissi/airlineinsurance
   ```
6. Verified with:

   ```
   sudo docker ps -l
   ```
7. Checking the logs

   ```
   sudo docker logs 8efba551fdc6
   ```

The resulted log is as follows:

```
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:9000
Server running at https://127.0.0.1:9030

/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:261
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:271:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:165:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1281:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I have included DockerFile for your reference

```
  # Tells the Docker which base image to start.
  FROM node

  # Adds files from the host file system into the Docker container.  
  ADD . /app

  # Sets the current working directory for subsequent instructions
  WORKDIR /app

   RUN npm install
   RUN npm install -g bower
   RUN bower install --allow-root
   RUN npm install -g nodemon

   #expose a port to allow external access
   EXPOSE 9030

   # Start mean application
   CMD ["nodemon", "server.js"]
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. You should, at least, include the error message and how you're starting the container.

Comment: The error message shows that mongodb connection failed to connect..can you provide some documents for deploying mean stack application in docker...

Comment: As I said, you didn't provide enough information to answer your question. Maybe it's related to how you're starting your containers, maybe it's related to your connection strings, maybe it's something else. If you want general instructions for deploying node applications with Docker, try Google.

Comment: I have mentioned the steps.You can pull the image of my application from DockerHub as crissi/airlineinsurance......Please do Check @ROMANARMY

Comment: You should edit your question to include all of those steps.

Comment: Ok..I will edit...Please do check my issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define your Dockerfile.
Since your app involves multiple processes (your app + mongodb), you could **[use supervisor to launch both](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/)**.

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27828210/6309) using a `supervisord.conf` like:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:mongod]
command=/usr/bin/mongod --smallfiles
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
autorestart=true

[program:nodejs]
command=nodejs /opt/app/server/server.js
```

Replace the nodejs command by your own application.

Comment: I have included DockerFile for your reference.Please do mention the modifications required for using Supervisor. @VonC

Comment: @criss you can add to your Dockerfile the part mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27828210/6309, and move your CMD command to `supervisor.conf`. The goal remains to have mongo and your app started.

Comment: I have tried but it returns with following error.                     docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"/usr/bin/supervisord\\\": stat /usr/bin/supervisord: no such file or directory\"\n"

Comment: @criss sure: you needd to install supervisor. Check the doc (https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/)

Comment: Can you help me to write DockerFile and supervisord.conf? Whether my DockerFile requires ubuntu and mongodb installation?...So Please do Clarify..I haven't any experience in using DockerFile.

Comment: @criss the supervisor.conf is pretty much the one illustrated above. And the Dockerfile is similar to the one mentioned in the doc.

Comment: @criss For docker itself, it is best to follow some tutorials first: http://docker.atbaker.me/exercises/exercise_1.html, https://www.katacoda.com/learn

Comment: @criss You can make a new question with the new Dockerfile and supervisor.conf, and start from there.

Comment: I have updated the question with new DockerFile and supervisord.conf...

Comment: @criss no I meant: make a *new* question: this one is already answered.

Comment: I have to wait to for five days for creating another question.

Comment: @criss Sorry, I had no idea. Try and create a new account. Modifying this question would only confuse everyone.